# in python, how to pause until certain time only without date in pause library

Tags: python, datetime, pause

I have python script and I want it to run at 10AM. I tried using with pause and datetime library like the code below

```
import pause
import datetime
pause.until(datetime.datetime(2021,1,6,10,00))
```

that means the script will pause until 6 January 2021 10.00 AM. What I want is, how to pause only certain time only the hour and the minute and seconds without putting the date there? is it possible?

Comment: You can calculate the number of second you need to pause (with `datetime` library), and just call `time.wait`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this library. I think it will suit your needs: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

You can code things like:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: i tried using the schedule but it doesn't wait until the certain given time and also doesn't run the function in the code.

Comment: That surprises me because I've used this library in the past without issues. Can you post some of the relevant code you are working on to show the exact problem?

Comment: here it is my test code https://ibb.co/VCRdYrm . So the current time in the screenshot is 12.04 and I want to schedule it at 12.08. I don't know why the schedule is skipped immediately and doesn't run the function

Comment: Python schedule uses a 24 hour clock. Did you want it to run at lunch time? Also, the program needs to be running at the specified time for it to work. You are also missing ```while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)```  See the docs here: https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: The line is skipped because it is waiting for the schedule.run_pending() to be called. With the schedule you will need to call eveything at once in a function at the specified time. I edited my answer to include the details you missed.

Comment: okay thanks, I did it and it works using the above solution. but how to do it just once and break the while loop after executing the function?

Comment: Glad I could help you. This article explains different ways of killing a python program: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/         When you get the chance do you mind marking my answer as correct?